# Can there be "an" "endemic"? (Can "endemic" legitimately be used as a noun?)

Tags: nouns

A recent AMA headline shouts: "The Resident Depression Endemic---and Solutions Underway".

Now, doctors are not known for their writing proficiency (self included here) but this seems to me to be a new or possibly just uninformed use of the word "endemic".

Probably this was a staffer who wasn't sure whether it was permissible to use the term "epidemic"...

Comment: Probably this was a staffer that had been on duty for 36 hours.

Comment: Worse yet, the article contains the subheading [**It’s an endemic**](http://www.ama-assn.org/ama/ama-wire/post/resident-depression-endemic-solutions-underway). How can anyone today trust doctors in training (or those writing about them?)

Comment: Funny comment, Phil, but staff members at AMA don't work such hours.

Comment: Well, I guess that followup comment was humor.  As it happens, the writer of the headline and subheading is, if I'm not mistaken, actually a lawyer.  Does that change anything?

Comment: @LouiseB.AndrewMDJD  Your comment assumes that we all know what "AMA" means.

Comment: Several dictionaries list "endemic" as a noun, but not in the above sense.

Answer (score 2):

*Endemic* as an adjective means regularly found in a specified population.  Its use as noun means an endemic disease.  The *OED* finds this usage from 1662 and quotes *The Saturday Review* (1859) for a figurative use thusly:

> Snobbishness in an **insidious** endemic.

For a literal use, we may consult [*An outline of the history and cure of fever, endemic and contagious*](https://books.google.com/books?id=X6tkAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA226&dq=%22an%20endemic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNn67X8sPMAhVG7iYKHZFYB8kQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q=%22an%20endemic%22&f=false) by R Jackson (1798)

> ... while contagious fever, occasionally exposed to pure air often
>   intermits or remits like an **endemic**;....

The noun usage seems as dated as Jackson's medical advice though.

One more example by request, from [*Medical Record*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8AZYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA385&dq=%22endemics%20and%20epidemics%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHkrnZ9cTMAhUK6iYKHaKrBc04ChDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=%22endemics%20and%20epidemics%22&f=false), Volume 35 (April 6, 1889), G F Shrady and T L Stedman eds.

> Only within the last twenty years, after the attention of medical men
>   had been drawn to repeated observations of **endemics** and epidemics
>   of pneumonia,....

Comment: Cool medical reference!  But I believe It's still being used as an adjective there.  Endemic being one type of fever, contagious the other.  The author juft neglected to ufe the word "fever" every time he fhould have...perhaps to save ink?  It was 1798...

Comment: But as to the Saturday Review, what WERE their editors thinking?  That's not a sentence!  Any other examples?  We need tie breaker that wasn't "in their cups" while writing...

Comment: @LouiseB.AndrewMDJD No, it's not an adjective, as the added example shows.  These are usages from the 19th century, when the word was commonly used as a noun.  It's no longer common, but that doesn't mean the writers and editors of the time were all drunk.  The *OED* not good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this was likely an error for epidemic. However, in a biological context (different field of biology than medicine) "an endemic" is often used to refer to an organism that is endemic to a particular area. Thus, "Species X is an endemic here." Or, "This island has many endemics" as a shorthand for "...many endemic species."

Comment: I can see that your second example serves as shorthand, but your first example, "Species X is an endemic here," seems to be just an unpleasantly long version of "Species X is endemic here."

Comment: In one sense, yes, but @deadrat wanted an example of possible use of "an endemic" and the use of endemic as a noun; this usage does both and implies that it is not the only endemic form.

Comment: Hmmm.  I would have thought "species X is an endemic here" would have been a shortened version of "species X is an endemic species here".  So still an adjective.  "Borrelia Burgdorferi is an endemic organism in white tailed deer ticks in Lyme CT."  Or "BB is endemic in Lyme deer ticks."

Answer (score -1):

So, this site https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/endemic
seems to offer a noun form that, albeit used infrequently, would fit the usage by the AMA author that first caught my eye.

I see that this was also explained by someone above, but somehow it didn't sound convincing given the context!  This does:

"Endemic n  a disease that is constantly present to a greater or lesser degree in people of a certain class or in people living in a particular location

Synonyms:
    endemic disease"

Ironically, the AMA writer copied the term directly from an editorial by a physician-writer and dean of a medical school, someone with whom I have worked on articles, and who seems to be a stickler for proper usage! Like me, probably had a schoolteacher mother...

Anyway, thanks everyone for considering with me!